# How to merge Consecutive duplicate status rows - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help me to merge the consecutive duplicate status rows into one. Please See below.

Example: My Current Table:

[image]

OUTPUT Should be:

[image]

Comment: They are not duplicate, the date is difference. Also you have a typo in your database.... :\

Comment: It should be:  `Failed: Invalid Address` (not `Inavlid` ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT ProductID, Status, MAX([Date]) AS RequestDate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ProductID, Status, YEAR([Date])
ORDER BY MAX([Date])
```

Comment: What happens when there are more of those sequences per year?

Comment: Good question.  Hopefully there would be a tracking number / transaction id to group them together.

Comment: What if I have more number of columns to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
select productid, status , max([date]) from table
group by productid, status
```